# Pen drive cannot be mounted

Tags: 12.04, mount, usb-drive

I get the following message when I insert my pen drive to USB port. I am unable to format it as well. (This pen drive earlier used as a bootable drive for Ubuntu 12.04)

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

lsusb command in the terminal gives the following message:

```
siva@siva:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. IR Receiver [built-in]
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:8281 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0951:1653 Kingston Technology
```

Comment: put this code : lsusb copy and paste output here ? i can fix that ... thank

Answer (score 1):

- Plugin the USB stick.
- Check the partition in the USB for errors:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb5
```

- You might have to change the partition name (`sdb5`). Look in the error window again when you mount it.

Comment: I get this message: fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

Comment: make sure you're typing `sdb5` and not `sdb`. The command should be: `sudo fsck /dev/sdb5`

Comment: if this doesn't work, try formatting the drive using gParted.